# Importing functions, variables from another file

Tags: vimrc

I am trying to spread up some functions across files to make it a bit more manageable (and also to see how that works. So far I have three dummy variables/functions in one file:

```
# second.vim
let newer = "as"
let s:older = "by" " note: this variable will not be imported if source'd
func LogOutput1(msg, level=g:log_level_default)
    " ...
endfunc

# vimrc
source second.vim
```

As far as I'm able to understand, it seems that running the `source` will import all 'global' items from `second.vim`, so that it will import:

- `newer`   <-- yes, global variable
- `s:older` <-- no, script-local
- `LogOutput1` <-- yes, 'global' (?) function

Is this accurate? What is the proper way to do imports, or is the above adequate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowadays (since vim7), we don't need `:source` any more -- except for reloading plugins while maintaining them

Distribute your scripts within

- {rtp}/plugin/ -- always loaded once after `.vimrc`
- {rtp}/ftplugin/ -- always loaded once per buffer with a matching filetype
- {rtp}/autoload/ -- lazily loaded, perfect for library plugin

Every thing is automatic. See this [old Q/A on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/147069/vim-plugin-creation-tutorial) (that should be moved here if somebody knows how it's done)